# Mapview mobile data consumption

Tags: android, android-mapview, consumption

i am working with google maps v2 api in my applicaiton. i am using a mapview inside a fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 this.mapMV.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 this.mapMV.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

          googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
          googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
          googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
          googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
       }
   });
}
```

everything works fine until i start moving in longer distance. during car ride google maps downloads cca 1 MB / min (for one day it is 300-400MB) vs. few kB in IOs version of this application.

Is there some way to reduce this huge data consumption?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved, this is my mistake, "problem" was in api call developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap – jakub